# Getting error for Data Reader in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mysqldatareader

Im facing the error when execute the data reader command in vb.net. it throw handling. This field like when you enter employee id in textbox then it will capture in database for other field name,department.

here is my code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection

Dim strConnectionString As String =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("testConnectionString").ConnectionString

Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT * hr_record WHERE Emplid='" & txt1.Text & "'"

Using sqlConn As New MySqlConnection(strConnectionString)

      Using sqlComm As New MySqlCommand()

      With sqlComm

        .CommandText = sqlQuery

          End With

              Try
                  sqlConn.Open()

                    Dim sqlReader As MySqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()

                    While sqlReader.Read()

                        txt1.Text = sqlReader("Emplid").ToString()

                        TextBox1.Text = sqlReader("Nama").ToString()

                        TextBox2.Text = sqlReader("DeptDesc").ToString()

                    End While

                Catch ex As MySqlException

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try

            End Using

        End Using

    End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Arion i get the error "Connection must be valid and open." at the line 'Dim sqlReader As MySqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()'

Comment: Shouldn't your query be `SELECT * FROM hr_record...`?

Comment: Try to move this code to a separate function.

Comment: @shree.pat18 tq i have change it but not function

Comment: @ray i just sperate it it seem no error but noting happen

Comment: From the error it sounds like you connection string is a possibly incorrect. Separately you need to consider SQL Injection (see http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html) your code is ripe for exploitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your select query like

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT * from hr_record WHERE Emplid='" & txt1.Text & "'"
```

*Note:- Cannot use code like that in `Page_Load`.Try to make one Function and call that function from `Page_Load` and always use `Parameterized query`.*

Updated answer:

**Page_Load**

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 DataBind()
 End Sub
```

**Outside Method:**

```
Public Sub DataBind()
Dim sConnection As String = "server=(local);uid=sa;pwd=PassWord;database=DatabaseName"
    Using Con As New MySqlConnection(sConnection)
        Con.Open()
        Using Com As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * from hr_record WHERE Emplid='"txt1.Text
        "'", Con)
            Using RDR = Com.ExecuteReader()
                If RDR.HasRows Then
                    Do While RDR.Read
                    txt1.Text = RDR.Item("Emplid").ToString()
                    TextBox1.Text = RDR.Item("Nama").ToString()
                    TextBox2.Text = RDR.Item("DeptDesc").ToString()
                    Loop
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        Con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Note:Try to implement your logic like that and also modified as per your requirements.

Hope it works.

Comment: i just overwrite the code but still have same error. by the way what i should do?? icant write in the page load?? so where is the right location i must write it.

Comment: You need to bind that `Page_Load` code in one method/Function and call that  method/Function from `Page_Load`..and also pass your connection and query to `MySqlCommand`...

Comment: i have done what you have told me but right now seem it like no error but it nof functioning when i enter the ID ,the another field not fill the data from database.

Comment: check the value of txt1.Text on page load

Answer (score 0):

You try to get Emplid in page load,but it's still nothing you should use button to check if  Emplid exist

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all thanks helping me..finally this code it works thanks to all .
 this the code will be function

```
 Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection

 Dim strConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("testConnectionString").ConnectionString


    Using sqlConn As New MySqlConnection(strConnectionString)
        sqlConn.Open()
        Using sqlComm As New MySqlCommand()

            sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn
            With sqlComm


                .CommandText = "SELECT * from hr_record WHERE Emplid='" & txt1.Text & "'"


            End With

            Try


                Dim sqlReader As MySqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()

                While sqlReader.Read()

                    txt1.Text = sqlReader("Emplid").ToString()

                    TextBox1.Text = sqlReader("Nama").ToString()

                    txtdep.Text = sqlReader("DeptDesc").ToString()

                End While

            Catch ex As MySqlException

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
            sqlConn.Close()
        End Using

    End Using

End Sub
```